# Why and how should the promise() method be used?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Consider the code snippet below. What will be the difference between the start and end times displayed? Why is the `.promise().done()` not responding?

```js
function getMinsSecs() {
  var dt = new Date();
  return dt.getMinutes() + ":" + dt.getSeconds();
}

$("#start").on("click", function() {
  $("p").append("Start time: " + getMinsSecs() + "<br />");
  
  $("div").each(function(i) {
    $(this).fadeOut(1000 * (i * 2));
  });
  
  $("div").promise().done(function() {
    $("p").append("End time: " + getMinsSecs() + "<br />");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><p></p></div>
<div><p></p></div>
<div><p></p></div>
<div><p></p></div>
<div><p></p></div>
<button id="start">Start time</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what will be the difference between the start and end times displayed?

The time difference will be the length it takes for all the queued animations on the `div` elements to complete

> why the .promise().done() isn't responding ?

It is. You just don't see the result in your example because the `p` tags are all hidden when the `fadeOut()` finishes, hence you cannot see the 'End Time` being output. If you use a different element to display that time it works fine:

```js
function getMinsSecs() {
  var dt = new Date();
  return dt.getMinutes() + ":" + dt.getSeconds();
}

$("#start").on("click", function() {
  $("p").append("Start time: " + getMinsSecs() + "<br />");
  $("div").each(function(i) {
    $(this).fadeOut(1000 * (i * 2));
  });
  $("div").promise().done(function() {
    $("span").append("End time: " + getMinsSecs() + "<br />");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><p></p></div>
<div><p></p></div>
<div><p></p></div>
<div><p></p></div>
<div><p></p></div>
<button id="start">Start time</button>

<span></span>
```